# Lubuntu 14.04 autologin problems

Tags: lubuntu, auto-login, lxdm

I'm having a login problem. When I Mark the autologin in the user and groups configuration in lxdm, it simply doesn't autologin and even I cannot login anymore, doesn't recognize my password. At least I can acess terminal. Could anyone sugest which file I must change to fix this? When didn't work, I checked /etc/lxdm/defaults.conf and its confogs hasn't change, still #autologin=dgod. Even when I changed that to my username, didn't work.

Comment: The `/etc/lxdm/defaults.conf` is owned by root.  Did you put `sudo` in front of your edit command?

Comment: Yes, I did. Let me explain accurately: I configured autologin in lxdm. When disn't work, I checked defaults.conf and its confogs hasn't change, still #autologin=dgod. Even when I changed that to my username, didn't work.

Comment: One more question.  Did you install the LXDE after installing Ubuntu?  The only reason I ask this, is because normal Ubuntu uses `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` where the autologin-user goes.  If not, ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf
```

edit

```
[SeatDefaults]

user-session=Lubuntu

autologin-user=usermane

autologin-user-timeout=delay
```

save

```
sudo vim /etc/lxdm/default.conf
```

edit
[base] uncomment and set autologin username to enable autologin

```
autologin=username
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Since `vim` is not the most user-friendly tool for the job, would you consider updating your answer with the keyboard shortcut needed to "edit" and "save". Alternatively, you might consider posting instructions involving `nano` or some other easier editor.